# Remove page number after reference

Tags: natbib, back-referencing

I'm having trouble trying to remove the page number hyperlinks displayed after references in the bibliography, for example:

> Huang, J. (1996). Efficient estimation for the proportional Hazards model with
>   interval censoring. The Annals of Statistics 24 540–568. 93, 99

I am using `imsbook` style for writing my thesis and since I have a glossary, I have used the package of `hyperref` in the following way:

```
\usepackage{hyperref, amssymb}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of abbreviations, notations and symbols}
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{~\dotfill~\hyperpage{#1}}
```

I mean in my document I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside,dvips]{imsbook}

\usepackage{hyperref, amssymb}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of abbreviations, notations and symbols}
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{~\dotfill~\hyperpage{#1}}

\begin{document}
.....
\end{document}
```

I am not able to remove those page numbers which is appearing after my references. May I request for any help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sure, I will edit the Q.

Comment: Is that really all you have in your preamble? Are you sure you use `biblatex` as your tag suggests - the version of `imsbook` I could find loads `natbib` for bibliography support.

Comment: I didn't get ur point Dear Moewe. I have one natbib.sty in related folder, but I don't know how to correct inside that file.

Comment: You see, your post is tagged `biblatex` which made me think you use `biblatex` as your bibliography package, yet `imsbooks` only loads `natbib`, so I don't know which package you use. Furthermore, it would be greatly appreciated if you posted a actual MWE, that is one that actually exhibits the issue you face. (Your MWE has no bibliography and hence no backrefs at all - it does not even compile without error.)

Comment: For calling my references I use following commands:      \bibliographystyle{imsart-nameyear} 
\bibliography{filename.bib}          What is MWE?

Comment: A [MWE (minimal working example (MWE))](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) is a short document that is compilable yet still exhibits the problem at hand. To create a MWE one normally strips away all the unneeded things until a truly minimal portion of code is obtained (see also the link for more information). Do you by chance have a set-up command for `hyperref` floating around? Search for `backref`, `pageref` in your document.

Comment: I know it is because of using usepackage{natbib}, but it will not be compiled if I remove this command.

Comment: I don't actually think it is `natbib`'s fault, and of course your document does not compile if you remove `natbib` if it contains cite commands. To analyse the problem further we really need a MWE that is narrowed down enough so that it exhibits the issue, but does not contain superfluous code, if you cannot provide one, we will have to close this question as unclear what you are asking because we have no means of telling exactly what causes this kind of behaviour in your document.

Comment: moewe already mentioned it. Search for `backref` in your document.